# Map Web Service output to HTML text box

Tags: html, web-services, webforms

How to use the output being returned by a web service in the same HTML page without opening a new page.

The current code I'm using is:

```
<form action='http://omarelsherif.com/Services/TestXMLWebService/TestService.asmx/HelloWorld3' method="post" target="_blank">
    <table align="center" cellpadding="5" width="400" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="100">

            Hello World 3</td>

            <td>
                <input class="frmInput" type="text" size="30" name="name" />
                <br />
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />                                       
                <br />                  
                <input class="frmOutput" type="text" size="30" name="HelloWorld3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I want to put the return value in the text box named frmOutput.

Answer (score 0):

If this is asp.net it will need to happen in the codebehind file.  You'll need to change (some of) your input fields to asp:controls so you can access in the codebehind.  In the code behind for your page you just need to assign the return value from the webservice to you field. Depending on what the webservice returns you might need to do some manipulation on the returned value before you assign it to the output control.

Comment: I know how to handle it in asp.net, and i have done. What i want to know is how to do this in HTML using text editor.

Comment: Omar, you probably want to explain that in your question, and probably re-name & re-tag your question to get the right people looking at it. I suspect this is a javascript/jquery question but I really don't know the answer you are looking for.